# Grouping by Column - Order Issue

Tags: r, dplyr

I have an issue with summarising after grouping by column. I have a data set that looks like this:

```
    ID       KEY
  320249T    75
  320249T    59
  320249T    83
  320249T    78
  320249T    42
  320249T    78
  320249T    42
```

(data has around 23 other columns, and around 2 million rows). The data is already ordered by data, i.e., the first row for a particular ID is the latest, and the last row, is the first one. I want to keep the KEY that is most repeated, so I do (df is my data set):

```
df.freq1 <- df %>% group_by(ID, KEY) %>% summarise(count=n())
```

which gives me as result:

```
      ID    KEY count
1:  320249T  42   2
2:  320249T  59   1
3:  320249T  75   1
4:  320249T  78   2
5:  320249T  83   1
```

In cases in which two (or more keys) have the same amount of "counts", I want to keep the last key in time, which in this particular case, would be 78 (if you see the first table). However, when I do:

```
df.freq1[,.SD[which.max(count),],by=ID]
```

I get

```
      ID    KEY count
1:  320249T  42     2
```

I guess it chooses 42 because of the order of the result of the grouping, so, how do I do it that the results of the grouping preserves the order of time of the original data frame?

Comment: You are mixing `dplyr` and `data.table` code, which one are you after? Also, we don't have `Pat_Code` or `Exa_SpeKey` in your data.

Comment: You are right, did not think of that. Data can get quite big, so perhaps would be better data.table. Variables should be correct now. Thanks!

Comment: Does it apply only when the counts are > 1?

Comment: For `dpyr`: `df %>% group_by(ID, KEY) %>% summarise(count=n()) %>%
  group_by(count) %>%  summarise(ID = last(ID),KEY = last(KEY))`

Comment: Thanks @JanLauGe. I guess from there I pick up the one with the larger count?

Comment: If you only want the largest one. I thought you might be interested in the last  entry for each possible count?

Comment: @JanLauGe, the `summarise` arranges by `key`, so `first` is no longer related to the original order.

Comment: It could be useful for future calculations, yes, you are right. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the most elegant, but this `dplyr` solution works, and avoids a slow arrange:

```
df %>%   
  mutate(order = row_number()) %>% 
  group_by(ID, KEY) %>% 
  summarise(n = n(),
            order = first(order)) %>% 
  filter(n == max(n)) %>% 
  slice(which.min(order))
```

> ```
> Source: local data frame [1 x 4]
> Groups: ID [1]
>
>        ID   KEY     n order
>     <chr> <int> <int> <int>
> 1 320249T    78     2     4
> ```